# How can I add a border around individual images, while keeping images aligned side by side?

Tags: html, css, image, border

I'm trying to get a border around each individual image while keeping them spaced out and in a rows of five.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please share the code you have written so far so that we can review and correct it

Answer (score 0):

Lets do it step by step.

First to align images next to each other with 5 images in a row, we can use css-grid. For thatw e need to wrap all images within a container. We apply `display: grid;` to the container. Then we use `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);` to apply 5 columns with equal size. So we will have 5 images within the same row of the exact size.

Applying a border will slightly break they layout. This is, because the border consumes extra space. To counter that, we can use `box-sizing: border-box;` to the images to size them all incl border and paddings. As such a broder will no longer extend the images size.

```css
.image-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-container img.border {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0721.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0722.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0723.jpg" class="border">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0727.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0730.jpg" class="border">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0731.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0732.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0733.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0734.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">
</div>
```